# Learning JAVA Programming - Where's best to start...?

Tags: java

I have a very basic knowledge of the Java language and how it works from reading the likes of Head First Java and the Dummies book.  I've not got to the end of either book as of yet and am really liking the Head First book as it is very useful and clear.

My question though is, what is the best app to make as a first app to help learn Java?  Would it be something like a calculator, or maybe a simple address book where you can input people and then search for them to return their data?

I'm just looking to put my knowledge so far to some use and having a bit of trouble thinking what a good App may be for a first app that will really help me as a beginner?

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Don't know if this is OT

Comment: Perhaps Programmers.StackExchange.com…?

Comment: Don't always abbreviate words or sentences in your future questions like **App**. You're using a Q&A site and not some social networking sites like FaceBook.

Comment: I wonder why no one has every asked this question before ... if they had, you would be able to search for the answers.

Comment: @Lion In no time, "app" will be part of the common dictionary terms, just like "google"

Comment: @eee:) It may sometimes merge with other meanings as it may stand for *application* or *approach* or something other.

Comment: @Lion I feel the word "app" to refer more towards an application rather than an approach as common as the trend in "Apple App Store", "killer app" and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java The Complete Reference, Seventh Edition

Ask such questions on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/